# Generating a column name row

Tags: java, jdbc

How would i generate a table consisting of the column names in an `SQL` Table and add it to a `JFRAME`/`JPANEL`.

I understand how to add it once i have it generated but how do i actually generate it?

table is called properties so im looking to `select * columnames from properties` and generate a `JTable` which i can then add to `JPANEL`.

Basically a horizontal row of columnnames eg...

PropertyID    Bedrooms    Address    Price    Type     Date Advertised

I have tried the following code but its only generating the table data rather than the column names.

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
        throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount-1; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }



    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set metadata contains the column name information.

```
  // Get the metadata
  ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData() ;

  // Print the column labels
  for( int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++ )
     System.out.print( md.getColumnLabel(i) + " " ) ;
  System.out.println() ;
```

googling result set metadata found this [example code](http://www.heimetli.ch/jdbc/JDBCMetaData.html)

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to get the job done in setting them individually. Could be cleaned with arrays and for loop.

```
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
            columnNames.setValueAt("PropertyID", 0, 0); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Beds", 0, 1); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(350);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Address", 0, 2); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(101);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Price", 0, 3); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(101);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Type", 0, 4); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(101);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Parking", 0, 5); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(101);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Condition", 0, 6); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(100);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Agent", 0, 7); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(100);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Show", 0, 8); 
            columnNames.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(101);
            columnNames.setValueAt("Ad Date", 0, 9);
```